which is a better way for "would' usage
If I write the examples given in another way, which one will be more appropriate?
Example 1) We cannot hire a taxi all the way. It would be very expensive.

a) We cannot hire a taxi all the way. I think/suppose/imagine it would be very expensive.
b) If we hired a taxi all the way, it would be very expensive.

Example 2) It would be unlucky to miss the next meeting.

a) I think/suppose/imagine it would be unlucky to miss the next
meeting.
b) If we missed the next meeting, it would be unlucky.


Example 1 has this qualification all the way.  Why are the proposed alternatives without that?

I have edited it. Thanks!

First of all, let's fix your misuse of a telic verb. You can't "hire" something all the way. Hiring is an event. You should use an atelic verb like 'take'. But unfortunately, your question is off-topic here. This site is only for questions on a specific point of learning English. We don't check writing, that is considered proofreading.

Neither is 'more appropriate' than the other. It depends on whether you want to include "I think" or its equivalent (implying that you are less certain).

"I know" or "I'm sure" would be better to express the certainty of the (b) version, although they're perhaps a bit more forceful - "I'm fairly sure" perhaps is closer. But I'm not sure what you actually want to know.

@StuartF I am trying to understand the meaning of "would." In many cases, 'would' is used for hypotheses. It is expressed as 1) conditional in some cases, 2) with words explicitly like in I imagine..., I suppose..., in case... of, etc. I have added a comment in the answer to this with few more examples. Thanks!

@Astralbee One can hire a taxi, mini bus, auto rickshaw or a metro taxi from anywhere in the city to reach there.
Retrieved from Wikipedia
The third night we were on the island, we hired a taxi to take us out on the town.
Times, Sunday Times
I had hired a taxi to tour the tombs and pagodas, but on an impulse also asked to be taken to the front.
Times, Sunday Times... Tourists are advised to negotiate the price for the trip before hiring the taxis.
Retrieved from Wikipedia CC BY-SA 3.0

@A_Mendes I don't think you understand what you're quoting. Saying "we hired a taxi all the way to London" is like saying "I was born all my life".

I thought that part is settled when I added my last comment. If I get that exact sentence later, I will add that link. :). I would think all the sentences that I wrote have more or less the same meaning, unless some one comes up with a clear answer.

I'm not sure I can trust the message, and don't want to hire a taxi all the way to the airport in Melbourne only to be turned down on the car rental. https://boards.cruisecritic.co.uk/topic/797350-great-ocean-road-is-this-plan-possible/. The comment surely is from a "native" in Florida.  If you search "hire a taxi all the way" you can get hundreds of links, many of them 'native.' Anyways, I will read about 'telic' verb after this :)

Would describes a hypothetical situation. "If we were to go all the way by taxi, it would be expensive." "If we were to stay in a hotel, it would be expensive"

@KateBunting 'would' for present/future is mostly used for hypothesis (apart from polite requests and offers) "We can't all stay in a hotel. It would be very expensive," has an implied hypothesis because of 'would' (e.g. from British council). As a native speaker, how do you differentiate in meaning between "Someone who liked Steve WOULD love Steve's father and "Someone who likes Steve WILL love Steve's father"?

The first implies that the prospect of a friend of Steve's meeting his father is hypothetical, the second that such a meeting is definitely going to happen.

@KateBunting Okay. Those two sentences are implied conditionals as per a good source.   Or, another way of writing the first one is: "If you liked Steve, you would love Steve's father." I think my initial sentences can be written as unreal conditionals (as written in option B in the question).

1b has a different meaning to 1a and the original 1. It doesn't say anything about whether you can or should hire the taxi, simply that it would be expensive if/when you did.
2a changes the meaning from the original, 2b does not (and is equivalent). 2a says thatit being unlucky is possible but not definite. 2b and 2 state that it would be unlucky as a bare fact.

I thought, among its different uses, 'would' is used here as a hypothesis. as in "used to refer to a situation that you can imagine happening"
"I would hate to miss the show." (I have changed the words of this Cambridge example) https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would.  2) From https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/wishes-hypotheses We use modals would and could for a hypothesis about the present or future... continued.

Britishcouncil example: "We can't all stay in a hotel. It would be very expensive."  Now, why can't we write it as a conditional as present unreal conditionals are used for hypotheses?

Also, for hypotheses, we use imagine explicitly as in "Imagine you won the lottery. What would you do with the money?" (words like imagine, suppose, in case of, etc  used explicitly to show hypotheses)

@A_Mendes, for "We can't all stay in a hotel. It would be very expensive." do you mean "If we stay in a hotel, it would be very expensive."? That would have a different meaning as it leaves open the possibility of staying at the hotel, which "can't" excludes.

Sentences with 'would' meant to be hypothesis are written in unreal conditionals i.e. If we STAYED in a hotel, it would be very expensive." That implies that we have very very less, or no chance of staying in a hotel.

@A_Mendes "If we STAYED in a hotel, it would be very expensive." does not in itself say anything about the possibility that we will stay in the hotel. It is more like an argument against staying in a hotel. I think this is an important distinction.
